# Google Sheets QUERY pulling from a list of tab names which will pull new tab data as new tabs are added

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-query-language

I have a Google Apps Script pulling the names of each tab in my Google Sheet into one list. The tabs are labeled by month and year (i.e., February 2020) but I don't have a tab for every single month since February. I create a new tab for months when I have new data which is not always every consecutive month.

With these tabs, I want to query all unique values across all tabs, in column D on each of the tabs. I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in anticipation for potential new tabs, so I don't have to go and update the query whenever I add a new tab?

Currently I have the list of existing tabs and concatenated to include the range (so each tab/range is listed as January 2020!A:D, for example) in cells C2:C6. The query I have that is correctly pulling unique values is:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({INDIRECT(C2);INDIRECT(C3);INDIRECT(C4);INDIRECT(C5);INDIRECT(C6)},"Select Col4 where Col4 is not null",1))
```

Is there a way to possibly add new month/dates to the list of existing tabs in anticipation of that tab name possibly being added in the future, and adding those not-yet-existing tab names into the query, but telling it to ignore it if it can't find that tab in the sheet?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several ways how to solve this:

- with a script that will pick sheet names
- without script using only formula
- with logic if the creation of sheets can be predicted

non-existing sheets can be ignored like this:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({
 IF(C2="", {"","","",""}, INDIRECT(C2));
 IF(C3="", {"","","",""}, INDIRECT(C3));
 IF(C4="", {"","","",""}, INDIRECT(C4));
 IF(C5="", {"","","",""}, INDIRECT(C5));
 IF(C6="", {"","","",""}, INDIRECT(C6))},
 "select Col4 where Col4 is not null", 1))
```

note 4 columns in A:D = 4 empty slots `{"","","",""}`

---

see:

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067831/5632629**

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/57452968/5632629**

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/58599649/5632629**

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/68447014/5632629**

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/61819704/5632629**